How to use different processes-per-resource (ppr) and processing elements (pe) for an hybrid MPMD program?
I am using mpirun to run a hybrid program as a Multiple Data Multiple Program (MPMD) application as follows:
mpirun -x OMP_NUM_THREADS=4 -x OMP_PLACES=cores -n 28 --map-by ppr:14:socket:pe=4  --host abc0:112 ./hello_world.exe : -x OMP_NUM_THREADS=8 -x OMP_PLACES=cores -n 14  --map-by ppr:7:socket:pe=8  --host xyz0:112 ./hello_world.exe

But the following OpenMPI/4.1.5 run-time error is produced:
Your job has requested more processes than the ppr for
this topology can support:

  App: ./hello_world.exe
  Number of procs:  28
  PPR: 7:socket

Please revise the conflict and try again.

I also tried it by specifying the --hostfile option with a separate host file for each application instance but the error is the same. Each node has 2 sockets with 56 cores each and I am trying to utilise all the cores but with a different process and thread count on each node.
Can someone advise on how to rectify the error ? Thank you in advance.
Additional information :
(A) SLURM version: slurm 23.02.7
(B) Allocating 2 nodes using:
salloc -N 2 -t 01:00:00 --exclusive

Each node has 2 sockets of 56 cores each.
(C) Compiled using: oneapi/2023.2.0 like:
mpicc -qopenmp hello_world.c -o hello_world.exe


This is clearly related to the way the job schedule and associated mpirun command are allocating resources, but you haven't told us what implementation those are... (or which compiler you're using to build the OpenMP code). More details, please.

@JimCownie : Many thanks Jim for the comment. I have added the information under "Additional information".

Slurm calls such execution a heterogeneous job: https://slurm.schedmd.com/heterogeneous_jobs.html  You should use srun rather than mpirun when using slurm. For portability, I prefer passing variables using env like in srun env OMP_NUM_THREADS=4 OMP_PLACES=cores ./hello_world.exe : env OMP_NUM_THREADS=8  OMP_PLACES=cores ./hello_world.exe. This avoids confusion for the different ways MPI implementations deal with variable propagation.

@Joachim : thank you for the comment. The idea here is to achieve it using mpirun of OpenMPI.
